# Disable a Band that has an Empty Data in Stimulsoft Reports

Tags: stimulsoft

I have a *Band* in a *Stimulsoft Report* which sometimes it have Empty Data.
When it's Empty, it shows the empty row and if numeric, it shows 0.

I want the band to display but I don't want it display when it's Empty.
How can I disable it?

If I should put a Condition, what is the command? & what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should use next expression DetaSource.Count == 0 and uncheck the Component Is Enabled option.